# POST response cached by default in volley

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

We have this use case

You can GET from /layout

You can also send data to layout using POST.

The GET response is being cached for 15 minutes, so any POST data is not being sent at all and the cached GET response is being served. In our opinion this is a major design flaw, if not a bug.

Am I missing something here? Why should the response of a POST request ever be cached?

Comment: I have never had any issues, could you pls post the request and the response data and also the networkmanager